# Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' when trying to build OpenCV for android samples

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

Hello guys I'm trying to learn about openCV in android
I've already following the instruction given [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package_using_with_NDK.html#android-binary-package-with-ndk)

but when I'm trying to compile I'm only getting

> 01:50:14 **** Auto Build of configuration Default for project
>   org.opencv.samples.fd.FdActivity ****
>   "C:\Android\android-ndk-r8\ndk-build.cmd"  Install:
>   libdetection_based_tracker.so =>
>   libs/armeabi-v7a/libdetection_based_tracker.so
>
> 01:50:14 Build Finished (took 184ms)

in the console
and I'm also get an error

> Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'CDT Builder'
>   on project 'org.opencv.samples.fd.FdActivity'. Internal error building
>   project org.opencv.samples.fd.FdActivity configuration Default
>   java.lang.NullPointerException Internal error building project
>   org.opencv.samples.fd.FdActivity configuration Default
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

anyone ever encountered this problem before?
please help me to solve this problem

thank you

Comment: Maybe building native code from command line will suffice?

Comment: I've been trying to build it from the command line like the tutorial give me,but the command line didn't compile and build but only showing  Install: libdetection_based_tracker.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libdetection_based_tracker.so

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try

Project Properties>C/C++ Build>Tool Chain Editor

> Current toolchain: Android GCC
>   Current builder: Android Builder

Project Properties>C/C++ Build

> (uncheck) use default build command
>   Build command: ndk-build
>   (uncheck) generate Makefiles automatically

Answer (score 2):

You may have renamed the project, and the eclipse forgot to rename the "Refresh Policy".

**Just update "Project properties -> C/C++ Build -> Refresh Policy" manually solved my problem**.

BTW, ADT has some very bad error descriptions as of in this case.

Comment: Thanks. This one just fixed my project build.

Answer (score 1):

I might have the same problem, 
try ndk-build -B which rebuild all the things, see whether you still got error, 
if no error remain, there is no problem with your ndk-build. try to run your android apps without CDT installed, if this works, at least we could use comand line to build the c++ part of code.

but CDT is still not working well, after I install the CDT according to the opencv doc, I got lots of errors, add the cygwin and gcc things to the path would solved most of it. But the last things every strange is, I got an error here.

in the face detection sample, .cpp part

```
catch(cv::Exception e)
{
    LOGD("nativeCreateObject catched cv::Exception: %s", e.what());
```

it always says symbol "e" can not be resolved.

but no error when I include the opencv things.
even when I try to put cv::Exception e outside of the catch()

Answer (score 1):

These works for me:

```
Build command: ndk-build
(uncheck) generate Makefiles automatically
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Eclipse and I was setting up the environment for C++ development. I created a "hello_world" project and tried to build it for the first time. However, I encountered an error saying that CMake was not found. To resolve this issue, I installed CMake and attempted to build the project again, then this error occurs:

```
Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'CDT Core Builder' on project 'hello_world'. Resource '/hello_world/build/default/compile_commands.json' does not exist. Resource '/hello_world/build/default/compile_commands.json' does not exist. Resource '/hello_world/build/default/compile_commands.json' does not exist. Resource '/hello_world/build/default/compile_commands.json' does not exist.
```

Fortunately, I found a solution by clicking on the Toolbar, then selecting Project -> C/C++ Index -> Freshen All Files. After performing this action and running the project again, the error disappeared.